# Passing loaded user ID into my action for update User Data (MERN ReactJS + Express)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, axios

I'm trying to update my user profile data from the client-side. The user has to upload a file and the component will catch the actual user-loaded ID, store it into a state, and then use this state to find the user in the database to update the value I need. But I can't figure out how to pass the state to filter the user; in the way you see below the It gives me a `PUT: http://localhost:3000/api/users/upgrade/undefined 404 (Not Found)`. Someone could help me?

Here's my server router:

```js
//SERVER ROUTER 

router.put("/upgrade/:id", upgrade.single("userPlus_doc"), (req, res) => {
  User.findById(req.params.id)
    .then((user) => {
      user.userPlus = true;
      user.userPlus_doc = req.file.originalname;

      user
        .save()
        .then(() => res.json("User Upgraded!"))
        .catch((err) => res.status(404).json({ success: false }));
    })

    .catch((err) => res.status(404).json({ success: false }));
});
```

My action and reducer:

```js
//ACTION

export const upgradeUser = (formData, id) => (dispatch, getState) => {
  axios
    .put(`/api/users/upgrade/${id}`, formData, tokenConfig(getState))
    .then((res) =>
      dispatch({
        type: USER_UPGRADE,
        payload: res.data,
      })
    )
    .catch((err) =>
      dispatch(returnErrors(err.response.data, err.response.status))
    );
};

export const setUserUpgradeID = (user_id) => (dispatch) => {
  dispatch({
    type: SET_USER_UPGRADE_ID,
    payload: user_id,
  });
};

//REDUCER

const initialState = {
  user_id: "",
};

export default function foo(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
  ...
  case SET_USER_UPGRADE_ID:
      return {
        ...state,
        user_id: action.payload,
      };
    case USER_UPGRADE:
      return {
        ...state,
        user: state.user.filter((user) => user._id !== action.payload),
      };
      default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

And how I pass the information client-side:

```js
class ProfileUpgrade extends Component {
  state = {
    userPlus_doc: "",
    user_id: "",
  };

  onFileChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({
      userPlus_doc: e.target.files[0],
    });

    this.props.setUserUpgradeID({
      user_id: this.props.auth.user._id,
    });
  };

  /* onChange = () => {

    this.props.setUserUpgradeID({
      user_id: this.props.auth.user._id,
    });
    console.log(this.props.setUserUpgradeID);
  };
 */
  onSubmit = (e, user_id) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const formData = new FormData();

    /* formData.append("userPlus", this.state.userPlus); */
    formData.append("userPlus_doc", this.state.userPlus_doc);

    this.props.upgradeUser(formData, this.props.user_id);
  };

  render() {
    return ( ... )
    }
}

ProfileUpgrade.propTypes = {
  auth: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  user: state.user,
  auth: state.auth,
  user_id: state.user_id,
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { upgradeUser, setUserUpgradeID })(
  ProfileUpgrade
);
```

The only things I need from the client-side are the doc title and the user ID to update the correct user object. To update the boolean `userPlus` I set the backend to set the value to true and save it.

Am I missing something in my action to make the component pass filter the user ID?

Comment: any suggestions??